# How do I get a fragment to load from an unspecified html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load, fragment

After making the menu disappear I cannot get my content to show without listing a specific html.

HERE is the HTML:

```
<div id="header">
<h1>N300 Project Gallery</h1>
</div>
<div id="container">
<div id="utility">
<ul>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>

</ul>

</div>
    <div id="index-content">?</div>
    <div id="footer">This is the footer</div>
</div>
```

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#utility a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#utility').hide('normal',loadContent);
    });
    function loadContent() {
        $('#index-content').load(url+ '#content')
    }
});
```

HERE IS THE FRAGMENT I WANT TO MOVE:

```
<div id="content">
    <p>Hello! My name is Brittany Shephard.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you need an extra space before `#content` in the URL you pass to `.load()` if you want the [fragment loading behavior](http://api.jquery.com/load/) (`+ ' #content'` instead of `+ '#content'`).

Your fragment is in a separate file, correct?

Assuming your fragment is returned from `projects.html #content`,  try:

```
function loadContent() {
    $('#index-content').load($(this).attr('href')+ ' #content');
}
```

From the [JQuery docs for hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), `this` is set to the hidden DOM node in the callback.  I'm assuming you want to load URL from the anchor you're hiding, so you need to grab the `href` attribute from that node.

Comment: Looks like it won't work, since the hidden element is not the link itself, but it's container.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the `url` in `loadContent()` coming from ?

In case you'll need to pass it from the `e.target` href attribute, create an anonymous function for hide's callback, and from the pass the url to loadContent. Somtehing like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#utility a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#utility').hide('normal', function() {
            loadContent($(e.target).attr('href'));
        });
    });

    function loadContent(url) {
        $('#index-content').load(url + ' #content');
    }
});
```

Comment: the url is a stand in for about.html, but I want to load a different ('page.html #content') based on the link clicked. Can you write out what you are describing?